# Execute second statement only after the first statement finished

Tags: mysql, pdo

From mysql table at first want to delete row. Only after the row deleted, i want to select sum(certain_column). Want to be sure that until row deleted, i do not execute select.

Decided to use such code like this:

```
try{ 

$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$db->beginTransaction();

try{ 
$stmt_delete = $db->prepare('DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `Id` = 1;');
$stmt_delete_items->execute( );
}
catch (PDOException $e){
echo "DataBase Error: " .htmlspecialchars( $e->getMessage() , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'<br>';
$db->rollBack();
exit;
}

try{ 
$stmt_select = $db->prepare('SELECT SUM(`Quantity`) AS `SumQuantity` FROM `table` WHERE `some_column` = 234;');
$stmt_select->execute( );
$arr_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
echo "DataBase Error: " .htmlspecialchars( $e->getMessage() , ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'<br>';
}

$db->commit();
}
```

Expecting at first execute `$stmt_delete` and only then `$stmt_select`. In usual case i get such execution order. But is it guaranteed 100%? Somewhere read that delete may take more time than select... with `exit;` i prevent next execution only in case of error. But i need to delay `$stmt_select` until `$stmt_delete`.

Or may be better to use `START TRANSACTION; ... COMMIT;`. Or may be for `DELETE` to use `LOCK TABLES ... UNLOCK TABLES`.

Please advice solution to be 100% sure that select executes only after delete is finished.

Comment: That's what a transaction does. But note that it's rare to want to DELETE data from databases, unless there is a legal requirement to do so. More usual is to simply mark data as 'hidden' or 'deleted' or visibility = 0, etc.

Comment: So with `$db->beginTransaction();` i can be 100% ? Ok, thanks.

Comment: This code smells. I see no need here for try-catch or for transactions. If the delete fails nothing else will be executed.

Comment: "try-catch or for transactions" used because want simpler to detect in which statement error exists (if incorrect code). Do these sub try/catch impact performance?